# Obtener parametro de url yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Estoy tratando de tomar el parámetro(144452) enviado por get el cual se encuentra en la url:

```
http://localhost/yii/basic/web/index.php?r=crud/editar/144452
```

Quisiera hacerlo asi para tener una url mas limpia en vez de poner &id=144452 pero no he conseguido hacerlo.
He tratado así:

```
Yii::$app->request->get('id')
```

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: y que te sale??

Answer (score 0):

Ya la variable la tienes declarada en el controlador, solo el mandar el id al form.

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'id'  => $id,

    ]);
}
```

Luego desde la vista update update.php

```
     <?= $this->render('_form', [
            'model' => $model,
            'id'  => $id,
        ]) ?>
```

Y en el formulario _form.php

```
Echo $id;
```